# Do I have to pay again to reinstall Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I installed the beta version of Minecraft on Android. Now the Google Play Store suggests for me to uninstall and reinstall the game:

[image: Play Store page showing Beta version warning]
<sup><sup>(click to expand)</sup></sup>

If I do this, do I need to buy the game again?

Answer (score 4):

No. If you have paid for it once, your google/app store account will have a record that you have paid for it already.

So when you choose to install it again, you won't be charged